# VBA: Disable button in Excel after first click

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to disable a button placed on my sheet1 once the user click on it.
I went through few old Stackoverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387721/vba-excel-disable-button) but dosent work as my expectation.

**The code:**

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Call FindADate

    Dim myshape As Shape: Set myshape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button 2")
    With myshape
        .ControlFormat.Enabled = False           '---> Disable the button
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15 '---> Grey out button label
    End With
End Sub
```

It actually grayed out the button which give a feel that the button is disabled but User can click again and again and it run my code.

Kindly let me know a solution to get the button disabled after 1 click, the button will be active again only once I close and re open the excel. (I am using MS Office professional Plus 2013)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not keep a variable to remember that it has been clicked?

Comment: Thanks @S Meaden will you show me how to do that

Answer (score 4):

You need to record somehow not to process the click.  You could examine the button's text colour and if grey then ignore the click.  Alternatively, you could set a variable either a global, module or static local variable.  I chose the static local variable in the code below, called `vDisable`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button2_Click()
    Static vDisable As Variant
    If IsEmpty(vDisable) Then
        
        Call FindADate
    
        Dim myshape As Shape: Set myshape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button 2")
        With myshape
            .ControlFormat.Enabled = False           '---> Disable the button
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15 '---> Grey out button label
        End With
        vDisable = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

after Dim line just write:

```
if myshape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15 then exit sub
```

that should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same situation and solved it by the following:

```
With myshape
     .OnAction = ""           '---> Removes any macro from the button
     .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15 '---> Grey out button label
End With
```

This removes the need for a global/static variable.